# Controlling processes execution using signals

Tags: c, process, signals, ipc, scheduling

I was given this particular task:

> Using SIGCONT, SIGSTOP, and SIGCHLD, write a program that accepts
>   through argv[] a list of commands (none of them has arguments) and
>   runs the commands in a round-robin style, alternating commands in
>   1-second intervals.

To achieve it, I tried this:

```
int dead_children = 0;
int nr_processes;

void inc_dead () {
    printf("I, %d, died\n", getpid());
    dead_children++;
    if (dead_children == nr_processes)
        _exit(0);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pids[argc - 1];
    nr_processes = argc - 1;
    signal(SIGCHLD, inc_dead);

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        pid_t pid;

        if ( (pid = fork()) == -1 ) {
            perror("fork");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if ( !pid ) {
            pause();
            execlp(argv[i], argv[i], (char *) NULL);
            perror("exec");
            _exit(1);
        }

        pids[i - 1] = pid;
    }

    while (dead_children < nr_processes)
        for (int j = 0; j < argc - 1; j++) {
            kill(pids[j], SIGCONT);
            sleep(1);
            kill(pids[j], SIGSTOP);
        }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I tried to run this code with very simple program that would allow me to verify task's correctness:

```
int main (void) {
    int i = 5;

    while (i-- > 0) {
        printf("This is %d saying HI!\n", getpid());
        sleep(1);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However, this does not work. I noticed that after creation, child processes never left `pause()` instruction, even though parent is sending a `SIGCONT`. Any thoughts on how to achieve the goal?

Comment: Simply dont use a `pause()`, it will not resume on SIGCONT. It only resumes after a signal-catching function has run.

Comment: You probably miss some Linux or POSIX tag

Comment: @spectras what should I use then? I need the child processes not to execute until parent sends first SIGCONT. Otherwise, they execute their code before reaching `while (dead_children < nr_processes)`

Comment: @Ricardo: Don't comment your own question, but do **edit your question** for clarification (and motivations)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch not finding where ... :/

Comment: @Ricardo> I would have the child processes send a SIGSTOP to themselves. `kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP)`.

Comment: don't use `printf` in `inc_dead` is not thread-safe

Comment: @SeekAddo *don't use `printf` in `inc_dead` is not thread-safe*  That's not quite the right reason that the use of `printf()` here is wrong.  `printf()` is not specified to be async-signal-safe, which is a much stricter requirement than just being thread-safe.  Thread-safe functions can do things like internal locking that change the state of a program.  Async-signal-safe functions can't.  Think of `malloc()` - internally it likely has some sort of locking mechanism. If a `malloc()` call is interrupted by a signal while it holds its lock, a call to `malloc()` in a signal handler breaks things.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yea, good to know.

Comment: @spectras but child processes call exec system call as soon as they left pause. After exec, any code is ignored, unless there was an error in exec itself

Comment: @Ricardo> I meant using `kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP)` **instead** of `pause()`. That should stop the child process like `pause()` does, except `SIGCONT` will wake it up.